# Auto login for Ubuntu (or other Linux) without GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, login, gui, defaults, autologin

I am thinking about doing an Ubuntu installation with their mini ISO, which comes only with the barebones system without a desktop environment/GUI.

I remember being given the option to set up automatic login when doing a full Ubuntu desktop installation, but how to I enable that for the mini ISO install? Did I miss something? Also, is there a generalised way to do this on any Linux OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find some ideas in [this thread of linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/autologin-without-gui-374338/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the tool **mingetty**. Concrete example and comparison in the [mythTV Wiki](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Frontend_Auto_Login).